# Stop people mapping my Drives

Tags: mappeddrive

I am on a network, and I'd like to control people mapping my drives.
Is there a way to globally stop all people from mapping any of my drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the domain policies/restrictions in place, some other possible avenues of "protecting" your files can be along the lines of:

- Firewall setting to block incoming TCP/UDP 135 through 139 and 445 ports
- Local (not domain) user rights against the directory and/or files
- Encrypting the files

Answer (score 3):

Set your shares up so only you have permissions to the shares.  If you're in a domain, though, any domain admin will still be able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Is your computer managed by a central AD domain? If so, there's probably not much you can do to permanently turn off sharing. If that's not the case, you can just turn off the "Windows File and Print Sharing" service.

Comment: "Windows File and Print Sharing" service? Never heard of it. You can though unbind the "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" component on your NIC (just one of many ways to stop users from mapping to your shares).

Comment: Maybe you're referring to the Server service?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Whoops, yep, you're correct. I was thinking of the server service.

Answer (score 0):

You can be successful in doing this using the security features offered in Windows.  However, be aware that the Domain Administrator can access you drives using the hidden share c$, d$, etc.  If I am not mistaken, isn't there a registry key that you can even prevent that from happening?